# Javascript scoping error function that returns functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

This is a simplified version of my function. The problem is that I get 2 both times in the alert. I believe this is a variable scope problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
var someObj = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2};

function getData(obj){
  var bunchOfFunctions = {};  
    for(var key in obj){
      value = obj[key];
        bunchOfFunctions[key] = function(){
            alert(value);
        }
    }
  return bunchOfFunctions;
}

var functs = getData(someObj);
for(var key in functs){
    functs[key]();
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/earlonrails/q4d66/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4d66/1/) of below answer

You will have to replace

```
  value = obj[key];
  bunchOfFunctions[key] = function(){
      alert(value);
  }
```

With:

```
  value = obj[key];
  bunchOfFunctions[key] = (function(value) { return function() {
      alert(value);
  } })(value)
```

This is because the `value` variable keeps changing, so once the loop is done running `value` is 2. What this code does is call a function with `value`, and that function returns another function. The other function it returns, however, now has the correct `value` because it is in its own scope.

Comment: Thnx man good answer! Also liked Pointy's but you had a working fiddle which I enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

It's kind-of a scope problem.  The issue is that each function in the bunch **shares** the same variable "value".  In your case, you forgot to declare "value" with `var`, so it's a global variable.

Even if you did use `var`, however, you'd have the same problem.

The trick is to introduce a new layer of scope by wrapping the creation of the function in yet another function.

```
    bunchOfFunctions[key] = function(valueCopy) {
      return function() {
        alert(valueCopy);
      };
    }(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the function containing the alert statement runs, it only see the value of the last interaction of the for statement

The solution to avoid this problem is:

```
var someObj = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2};

function getData(obj){
  var bunchOfFunctions = {};  
  for(var key in obj){
    var value = obj[key];
    bunchOfFunctions[key] = (function(x){
        return function() {
            alert(x);
        }
    })(value)
  }
  return bunchOfFunctions;
}

var functs = getData(someObj);
for(var key in functs){
   functs[key]();
}
```